# Elasticsearhc filter sub object before search

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have index like this:

```
{
    "id": 6,
    "name": "some name",
    "users": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "User1",
        "isEnabled": false,
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "User2",
        "isEnabled": false,
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "User3,
        "isEnabled": true,
      },
    ]
}
```

what I need is to return that index while user searching for the name `some name`, but also I want to filter out all not enabled users, and if there is not enabled users omit that index.

I tried to use filters like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "name": "some name"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "users.isEnabled": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but in such a case I see index with all users no matter if user is enabled or not. I'm a bit new but is there a way to do so??? I can filter out all that in code after getting data from elasticsearch but in such a case it can break pagination if I remove some index without enabled users from result set.

I'm a bit new to elasticsearch, but as far I can't find how to do it. Thank you in advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch will return whole document if there is any match. If you update your mapping and make users array nested, you can achieve this by using inner hits. This is a basic example mapping that works:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "users": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And if you send a query like following, response will contain id and name from the parent document, and it will contain inner_hits that match to your user's isEnabled query.

```
{
  "_source": ["id", "name"], 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "some name"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "users",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "users.isEnabled": {
                  "value": true
                }
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This is an example response

```
{
  "took" : 7,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.9375811,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.9375811,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "some name",
          "id" : 6
        },
        "inner_hits" : {
          "users" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 1,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 1.540445,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "test",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "1",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "users",
                    "offset" : 2
                  },
                  "_score" : 1.540445,
                  "_source" : {
                    "id" : 3,
                    "name" : "User3",
                    "isEnabled" : true
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then you can do the mapping in the application.